# Connect to PostgreSQL via PhpStorm

Tags: postgresql, ubuntu, phpstorm

I have started learning the PostgreSQL and can't get how can I connect to database via PhpStorm. It always asking for password, but, as I understood, there is no password.

Right now I'm able to connect postgres server like that:

```
sudo -i -u postgres
```

I'm able to create new user, role, db and etc. Any ideas?

P.S. Using Ubuntu, if it's necessary

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution is available via https://help.ubuntu.com/stable/serverguide/postgresql.html

To resolve this problem we need to change the authentication method. So the steps is:

Firstable, add new password for postgres, using this:

```
sudo -i -u postgres
psql
ALTER USER postgres with encrypted password 'your_password';
```

Then, open the configuration file

```
sudo nano /etc/postgres/9.x/main/pg_hba.conf
```

(Replace 9.x with your version of postgre)

Change this string

```
local   all             postgres                                peer
```

to

```
local   all             postgres                                md5
```

and for the last:

```
sudo service postgresql restart
```

And you are there.

Comment: Does `sudo -i -u postgres` still works after the change?

Comment: Yes, but it ask for password now

Comment: If you want to connect to the local PostgreSQL from you local OS account without prompting for the password then create PostgreSQL user with the name equal to the OS user and add record for it to the `pg_hba.conf` like for `postgres` user: `local all <your_os_user_name> peer`